# Using trie to hold library of ascii values, rather than strings?

Tags: trie

I learned about tries in my class and I was just curious if it would be a good way to implement storing individual ascii characters, rather than strings.

For example, using a trie to be able to convert to any base.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use-case? What do you think will be easier/better? Why do you store individual characters to begin with? There's so few individual characters, why care at all?

Comment: @Evert Id store all the ascii values to make a base 128 number system. It might be the same as just hard coding the ascii values, but it was just and idea I randomly had

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are hardcoding and how this would be different in a trie. Valid ASCII characters are also just byte values. You have to describe your question better and maybe show some exampels. Aside: not all values in the ascii range are usuable.